# How to select icon from an image file

Tags: image, file, icons, extract

Basically in many web frameworks and templates such as jquery UI they provide an image file which contains all the icons used in a framework. What I need is to select particular icon from this image file(framework uses it for its own widgets), how to do that? I know the benefits behind putting icons in a single image file, but not the technique to retrieve them.

[image]

Comment: Since you mention jquery, you are actually interested in CSS Sprites (see http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/). I guess you also didn't bother checking related questions around SO.